# How can I store and forward slots using boost::signals2?

Tags: c++, boost-signals2

I have a problem where I'm having to instantiate instances of objects
earlier than I would like to do so because I need to connect signal
slots through some deep ownership, and I'd like to come up with a way of
storing and forwarding the slots so that I can construct objects closer
to their use site, instead of doing so as member variables.

My basic problem is that I have a process that will download an update
file on a separate thread and send a progress signal to anyone who is
interested. The signal is essentially:

```cpp
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (double)> DownloadProgress;
```

Assume that the implementation of the `progress` function mentioned
below conforms to this; the nature of the signal itself isn't very
important (although I am using functors for the most part).

The signal is set and the code is called something like this:

```cpp
Updater updater;
updater.onDownloadProgress(&progress);
updater.runDownloadTask();
```

When you call `updater.runDownloadTask()`, it will start the
`UpdaterDownloadTask`, which starts an `HTTPRequest` and returns an
`HTTPResponse`. The `HTTPResponse` is the piece which interacts with the
network layer and receives the data and contains the `DownloadProgress`
signal. With this, my implementation looks a bit like (bottom-up from
`HTTPResponse`, heavily abbreviated to elide methods that aren't
particularly illustrative):

```cpp
class HTTPResponse
{
public:
  // this will be called for every "chunk" the underlying HTTP
  // library receives
  void processData(const char* data, size_t size)
  {
    // process the data and then send the progress signal
    // assume that currentSize_ and totalSize_ are properly set
    progressSignal_(currentSize_ * 100.0 / totalSize_);
  }

  void onDownloadProgress(const DownloadProgress::slot_type& slot)
  {
    progressSignal_.connect(slot);
  }

private:
  DownloadProgress progressSignal_;
};

class HTTPRequest
{
public:
  HTTPRequest() : response_(new HTTPResponse) { }

  void onDownloadProgress(const DownloadProgress::slot_type& slot)
  {
    response_->connect(slot);
  }

  boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse> perform()
  {
    // start the request, which operates on response_.
    return response_;
  }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse> response_;
};

class UpdaterDownloadTask : public AsyncTask
{
public:
  DownloadTask() : request_(new HTTPRequest) { }

  void onDownloadProgress(const DownloadProgress::slot_type& slot)
  {
    request_->connect(slot);
  }

  void run()
  {
    // set up the request_ and:
    request_>perform();
  }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest> request_;
};

class Updater
{
public:
  Updater() : downloadTask_(new UpdaterDownloadTask) { }
  void onDownloadProgress(const DownloadProgress::slot_type& slot)
  {
    downloadTask_->onDownloadProgress(slot);
  }

  void runDownloadTask() { downloadTask_.submit() }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<UpdaterDownloadTask> downloadTask_;
};
```

So, my Updater has to have an instance of `UpdaterDownloadTask` that's
always around, which has an instance of `HTTPRequest`, which has an
instance of `HTTPResponse`—just because I have to forward the slot
connection from `Updater` (the public API entry point) to `HTTPResponse`
(where the signal belongs).

I would rather implement `UpdaterDownloadTask::run()` like so:

```cpp
void run()
{
  HTTPRequest request;
  request.onDownloadProgress(slots_);

#if 0
  // The above is more or less equivalent to
  BOOST_FOREACH(const DownloadProgress::slot_type& slot, slots_)
  {
      request.onDownloadProgress(slot);
  }
#endif

  request.perform();
}
```

This would have similar implications at the HTTPRequest level (so I
don't have to construct the HTTPResponse until I perform the request)
and overall make for a nicer data flow with strong RAII semantics. I've
previously tried defining the `slots_` variable as a vector:

```cpp
std::vector<DownloadProgress::slot_type> slots_;
```

Yet I can only get this to work if I force the callers to call
`onDownloadProgress(boost::ref(slot));`.

Has anyone done this successfully, or have a good suggestion on how to
store and forward other than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think storing the slots in a vector should work ok. If you want to get rid of the need for `boost::ref(...)` you can remove the `&` from the `onDownloadProgress` parameter (since `slot_type` is copyable).

Alternatively, you could have your signal inside `HTTPResponse` fire and in turn fire a signal in `HTTPRequest`, doing that, you could connect all the slots to the signal in `HTTPRequest`, then once the `HTTPResponse` is created, you connect to the response signal `onDownloadProgress(request.signalname)`. Where `signalname` is the signal your client.

pseudocode:

```
Request request;
request.onProgress(myProgressBarCallback);
    //calls: this.signal.connect(myProgressBarCallback);
request.go();
    //calls: Response response;
    //  and: response.onProgress(this.signal);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried some things with a vector previously, but it may have been an error on my part. I think you're right.